# Can we make a bridge between NodeJS and Maven Java application?

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm

I have a maven based Spark standalone application. Suppose main class of an application is "HelloWorldnAddition.java". I can easily run its main class by throwing command `exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=HelloWorldnAddition`.

I understand the npm java and knows that how simple java class can connect with NodeJS and we can easily call methods of java class in NodeJS *.js page like

## !/usr/bin/env node

```
var java = require("../");
java.classpath.push("./src");
var MyClass = java.import("com.nearinfinity.nodeJava.MyClass");
var result = MyClass.addNumbersSync(1, 4);
console.log(result);
```

I want the exact thing with maven project, that I can easily call maven class in my NodeJS *.js page and call its method like above. Is there any way to do this. I tried multiple maven packages in npm but seems everything useless.

Comment: Are you using something like https://github.com/joeferner/node-java or how do you call Java out of Node.js?

Comment: yes for the simple java, I am using the same. But I really want to do it with Maven Project. Do you have any idea or help?

Comment: I did it ...and runs fine :)